# Laravel SoftDelete, delete and Update not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use Laravel REST API and I came across this problem. I can't seem to delete, forceDelete or even updating this model (haven't tried with any other model).

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Multimedia extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes; 

    protected $fillable = ['Path', 'Type'];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function category()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories');
    }
}
```

Controller:

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use App\Multimedia;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Log;
use Carbon;

class MultimediaController extends Controller
{
    public function delete(Multimedia $multimedia)
{

    //Option 1
    $multimedia->delete();
    return response()->json(null, 204);

    //Option 2
    $multimedia->forceDelete();
    return response()->json(null, 204);

    //Option 3
    $multimedia->updated_at = Carbon::now();
    $multimedia->deleted_at = Carbon::now();
    $multimedia->update();
    return response()->json(null, 204);

    //Option 4
    DB::delete('DELETE FROM multimedia WHERE ID=' . $multimedia->ID);
    return response()->json(null, 204);

    //Option 5 (In response to suniti yadav) THIS ONE WORKS.
    $multimedia->where('id', '=', $multimedia->ID)->delete();
    return response()->json(null, 204);
}
}
```

Only option 4 works (it is equivalent as a Force Delete). In Option 1 and 3, if I send the $multimedia object onto the JSON, I can see the updated_at and deleted_at are set to current time.

Routes:

```
Route::delete('multimedia/{multimedia}', 'MultimediaController@delete');
```

Any Ideias?

Thanks!

EDIT: I implemented this on two migrations

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMultimediaTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Multimedia', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('ID');
            $table->string('Path', 200)->unique();
            $table->enum('Type', ['Image', 'Video'])->default('Image');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('multimedia');
    }
}
```

Migartion 2

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddCategoryOnMultimedia extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('Multimedia', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('Category', 200);
            $table->foreign('Category')->references('Name')->on('Categories');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Added a picture of a registry from PHPMyAdmin

[image: PHPMyAdmin View]

EDIT 3: I continue experiencing this problem event after the answer of suniti yadav

I have this on another controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $price = new Prices();
    $price['Price'] = $request->input('Price');
    $price['FromDate'] = date_create($request->input('FromDate'));
    if($request->has('ToDate'))
        $price['ToDate'] = date_create($request->input('ToDate'));
    $price['Type'] = $request->input('Type');

    if($price['Type'] == 'Regular')
    {
        $lastRegularPrice = Prices::where('Type', '=', 'Regular')->orderBy('FromDate', 'DESC')->take(1)->get()->first();
        $priceDate = Carbon::parse($price['FromDate']);
        //return response()->json($lastRegularPrice, 406);

        if($priceDate->lte($lastRegularPrice->FromDate))
        {
            $error["error"] = "Cannot add new 'Regular' price starting from " . $priceDate->toDateString() . " due to being before the current 'Regular' price starting from " . $lastRegularPrice->FromDate->toDateString();
            $error["status"] = 406 ;
            return response()->json($error, 406);
        }

        $priceDate->subDay();
        $lastRegularPrice->ToDate = $priceDate;
        $lastRegularPrice->save();
    }
    else if($price['Type'] == 'Promo')
    {

    }
    $price->save();
    return response()->json($price, 201);
}
```

the variable lastRegularPrice is never updated on the database. Any Help?

Comment: `DB::delete('DELETE FROM multimedia WHERE ' . $multimedia->ID)` this line would delete all the rows of the table.

Comment: Yes, My mistake, I already fixed that on the example. Any Ideias why Foce delete, update or delete don't work?

Comment: Have you declared in your `Schema` -> `$table->softDeletes();`?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I added them on the question.

Comment: I think he has created migration to create deleted_at column as he can update & see it @AntonisTsimourtos

Comment: _In addition to actually removing records from your database, Eloquent can also "soft delete" models. When models are soft deleted, * they are not actually removed from your database *. Instead, a  deleted_at attribute is set on the model and inserted into the database. If a model has a non-null  deleted_at value, the model has been soft deleted. To enable soft deletes for a model, use the  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes trait on the model and add the deleted_at column to your $dates property:_ That being said, when using `delete()` won't delete the record from db.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos You can see all of that is there, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @RicardoAlves Are you looking to permanently delete or just soft delete the row ?

Comment: Does `deleted_at` gets updated when you use option 1,2? @RicardoAlves

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos No. But if, instead of the return in the code I use this one (return response()->json($multimedia, 200); ) I can see via PostMan that it return the "deleted_at" and "updated_at" being set to the current date. If then I go to PHPMyAdmin, I can see those two columns were not updated.

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva I was looking at soft delete the row, but since I lost already almost 5 hours in this problem I want something that just works (my cliente hasn't requested soft delete).

Comment: @RicardoAlves If soft delete isn't necessary, I would suggest you to simply delete the record. That'll work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned 'id' to which record you want to delete or update.

```
//Option 1
$multimedia->where('id', '=', $multimedia->ID)->delete();

//Option 1 or 2

    $m = $multimedia->withTrashed()->findOrFail($multimedia->ID);
    if(!m->trashed()){
      $m->delete();
    }
    else {
      $m->forceDelete();
    }

//Option 2
    $multimedia->where('id', '=', $multimedia->ID)->forceDelete();

 //Option 3

    $data = [
       'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
       'deleted_at' => Carbon::now()
   ];

    $multimedia->where('id', '=', $multimedia->ID)->update($data);
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I tried that. I added the code I run as an option 5. It worked with your line of code. Why the others doesn't?

Comment: Thank your for your answer. That indeed work, but shouldn't the model received as an argument already be the one I want to delete? Shouldn't my code work?

Comment: i have given answer for all the other option as well , And the issue was multimedia is was missing. I mean you are performing alteration query but u have missed to provide which row is going to alter. So that 'id' is important.

Comment: No without providing id or any other field it wont work.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it works. But, if I"print" the $multimedia object I received as argument, I can see all columns with the correct data, although I only passed the ID via URL. Shouldn't that object be enough to refer to the row?

Comment: @sunitiyadav it has route model binding, so `$multimedia` is a model object, you don't need to use query builder on it.

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva : $multimedia is object of class Multimedia model, but for alteration it requires multimedia id.

Comment: @RicardoAlves: what's the issue ? You haven't received your expected answer.

Comment: @sunitiyadav Update does not work. Please see EDIT 3, where I fetch a row from the database but it is still not updating.

Comment: @sunitiyadav It worked now using your example. Thank you!